# <br /> in .tpl files

Tags: php, html, smarty

How can I type `<br />` in **.tpl files** ?

I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <br />
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {\n}
```

But both didn't work, can someone help me please?

Comment: Is your <br> inside a string?

Comment: Format and remove thanks.

Comment: @Viney no it isn't

Comment: What means _didn't work_? Tpl is _normal_ HTML template, so using `<br>` is the right way.